# d3> How can I append only new circles without recycling previous circles?

Tags: d3.js, svg, geometry

## When I do this function

```
function d3add()
{d3.select('svg').selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append('circle')
   .attr('id',function(d){return d.id;});}"
```

and then make it repeated several times with different data.

I find some circles have the same id when they should have different ids.
I think the reason is d3's recycling circles having only different positions.
I need to show all circles appended every time the function is called, with different ids.

How can I stop recycling and just append new circles into one svg?

Is there any option for "selectAll('circle')"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your problem is, but try providing a key function.

`.data(data,function(d){return d.id})`

If you provide data with different id's, you should have no more "recycling" of circles.

Comment: Thank you. I solved by the way of updating data(accumulating previous data and new data) and removing all previous circles(and then select all circle) whenever repeating the function. Any way you nice guy~